# disable next button from paginator in primeng p-table

Tags: css, angular, datatable, pagination, primeng

I would like to disable next button from the paginator of p-table if a boolean is false..

Here is my p-table:

```
<p-table #dt id="{{id}}_table" [(value)]="_datasrc" [columns]="cols" [rows]="rowNumber || 10"
         [paginator]="paginator" [pageLinks]="1" ...
```

You can see my css code in order to disable the button:

```
::ng-deep 
     .ui-paginator-next {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

How to enable the css code only if my boolean is true, I want to use ngClass in p-table tag but it won't affect the paginator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the table, like you said, using ngClass or like this:

```
[class.hide-next]="hideNext"
```

In your CSS ruleset, add this class to your selector, like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    .hide-next .ui-paginator-next {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

You can see a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledoc-demo-di73v7?file=src/app/app.component.html). I've used the primeNG demo and added what I've written above and a toggle button for the paginator's next button.
**Note:** The class names are slightly different than what you wrote. I assume it's due to version differences.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but id didn't work for me.. the next is not hidden when this condition is true 
if (ds.length < this.rows)  this.disableNextButton = true

Comment: p-table is not taking the "hide-next" class when the boolean is true.
Ps: the boolean becomes true when the length of the table is < than the rows option

Comment: Is the boolean being changed in a synchronous code or in an asynchronous code? If it's the latter, you should call `markForCheck` on the `changeDetectorRef` .